# SQL query: retrieve existing dates period with overlap

Tags: mysql, sql

I got quite a complexe product/availability problem, that I just can't solved, and I didn't find any similar question anywhere.

Table "**product**" :

```
- id
- name
```

Table "**period**" :

```
- id
- start (Date)
- end (Date)
- price (int)
- product_id
```

A **product** can be associated to many **period** in my case, even within the same date range (start/end).

*Examples:* for a product "**A**"

period 1) **start**: 2013-01-01 || **end**:   2013-01-07 || **price**: 200

period 2) **start**: 2013-01-07 || **end**:   2013-01-14 || **price**: 250

period 3) **start**: 2013-01-07 || **end**:   2013-01-10 || **price**: 100 ## included in the period (2) above

period 4) **start**: 2013-01-10 || **end**:   2013-01-14 || **price**: 200 ## included in the period (2) above

period 5) **start**: 2013-01-11 || **end**:   2013-01-14 || **price**: 150 ## included in the period (2) above

What I need to do is retrieve all the products and their prices for a given date range.

**What a user would search, and what I want to obtain:**

- Search for products between 2013-01-01 and 2013-01-07: it should return product **A** and a price of 200 (period 1).
- Search between 2013-01-**02** and 2013-01-07: it should **not** return product **A**, because the period is not completely included (day 2013-01-01 is missing).
- Search between 2013-01-07 and 2013-01-14 (most complexe case): it should return product **A**, with "two" possible periods: (2) and (3 + 4). But it should not return period (3+5) because there is a "hole" for day 2013-01-10.

I would also like to be able to retrieve the lowest price. In the third case above, it should return 250, because (2) price is lowest than (3+4) price.

Any help would be very apreciated.

Comment: Do you ever have to consider more than two ranges that might be combined?

Comment: Yes, something like 2013/01/01-2013/01/02 + 2013/01/02-2013/01/03 +  2013/01/03-2013/01/07 should match search for 2013/01/01-2013-01-07

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution, but it is too long for a comment.

What you are asking to do is almost impossible in SQL and very difficult in a programming language.  To solve this, you need to find all possible "tilings" of time between two dates.  A tile is an individual record and a tiling is a set of records that cover the time period.

The problem is that there are many different possible solutions, all of different sizes.

In a programming language that supports recursion, you might take a dynamic programming approach.  This would basically start with any period, then recurse to solve the problem, then consider the next period (a depth-first approach).  That is not easy to implement in SQL.

Perhaps there are additional constraints on the problem that would make this more tractable.  Or, perhaps someone else will understand it in a different way and see a solution (that would be quite interesting).  My opinion, though, is that this is not worth doing in SQL, unless you can further constrain the problem.